# Rails 4 association connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm trying to figure out the association between 3 models I have.

Challenge, Sip, User

User can create a Sip, and Users can submit Challenges to that Sip; Sips has many Challenges

**challenge.rb**

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :sip, counter_cache: true
end
```

**sip.rb**

```
class Sip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :challenges
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :challenges
  has_many :sips
end
```

Here are the columns:

```
Challenge: id, user_id, sip_id
Sip: id, user_id
User: id
```

In in my sip view, I'm trying to get a list of users like this:

```
- @sip.each do |sip|
  = sip.challenges.users.to_json
```

Ultimately, I want to get all the users that have submitted challenges that belongs to `sip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sip.challenges` is a collection, you have to `map` over it to get the users. That's going to get you a collection of collections of users, so you `flatten` it, and `uniq` it, and `compact` it to remove any `nil`s:

`sip.challenges.map(&:user).flatten.uniq.compact`

`flatten` turns `[[1,2], [2,3]]` into `[1,2,2,3]`, `uniq` turns that into `[1,2,3]`.

`map(&:user)` sends `user` to each item in the enumerable (collection) that's to the left of `map`, in this case, to each challenge in `challenges`.

Is this efficient? Uh... left as an exercise for you.

Edit: To add HTML tags: The result of doing all that is itself an `Enumerable`, so you can `each` over it:

```
%ul
  - sip.challenges.map(&:user).flatten.uniq.compact.each do |user|
    %li= user
```

Comment: You don't need `flatten` though because each challenge only has one user.

Comment: How do I apply html tags to each loop?